# Angular2 - Dynamic Loading of I18N Files with angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-translate

### Context

I have an angular 2 app which should be translated into different languages, when there are typos or if the customer wants to change a translation, the translation files should be reloaded (if you refresh the page in the browser).

### Questions

Is it possible to dynamically load translation files (meaning: they can be changed on the server and are reloaded on page refresh, without needing to recompile the angular 2 app) with the angular 2 translation tools and angular-cli?

---

AFAIK the `angular-cli` will build a new translated angular 2 app for a specified translation file.

- Can I use the `angular-cli` and load translation files dynamically?

---

If I can't use `angular-cli` and switch to `system.js`:

- Can I use `angular-cli` for development and `system.js` for deployment?
- Do I have to switch completly from `angular-cli` to `system.js` (also for local development)?
- Can I precompile the app with `system.js` and still load the translation files dynamically?

---

If I want to use `angular-cli`:

- Should I switch to the `ng2-translate` library?
- Are there other alternatives to compile the app but dynamically load the translation files?